# Tensorflow Lite GPU support for python

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

Anyone know if Tensorflow Lite has GPU support for Python? I've seen guides for Android and iOS, but I haven't come across anything about Python. If `tensorflow-gpu` is installed and `tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter` is imported, will GPU be used automatically?

Comment: Yes! It automatically process the data on GPU. But if you want to use tensorflow lite in any embedded devices than tensorflow provides **TensorFlow Lite GPU delegate**. You can read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu) for more information.

Comment: @kruxx But the guide doesn't seem to suggest Python is supported. Does that mean TFLite doesn't support GPU for Python then?

Comment: If you change your device in `tf.device` from CPU to GPU and you can use the same model to run on GPU as well.

Comment: @kruxx I've tried that, but I'm not getting any GPU activity. Is the only way to get the GPU to do the processing by means of GPU delegate though? If so, setting `tf.device` wouldn't be adequate.

Comment: @JohnM are there any news on this topic? Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31377) thread, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to convert tflite to onnx and use onnxruntime-gpu

convert to onnx with https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx:

```
pip install tf2onnx
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --opset 11 --tflite path/to/model.tflite  --output path/to/model.onnx
```

then `pip install onnxruntime-gpu`

and run like:

```
session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(('/path/to/model.onnx'))
raw_output = self.detection_session.run(['output_name'], {'input_name': img})
```

you can get the input and output names by:

```
for i in range(len(session.get_inputs)):
    print(session.get_inputs()[i].name)
```

and the same but replace 'get_inputs' with 'get_outputs'

Answer (score -1):

You can force the computation to take place on a GPU:

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
   for i in range(10):
         t = np.random.randint(len(x_test) )
         ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I'm trying to run `tensorflow.lite.python.interpreter` on GPU. I get no GPU activity if I wrap it under `tf.device`.

Comment: This solution is for Tensorflow itself, for TFLite it will not work.